# Extract geojosn basis country and rewrite to file in php - don't know where to start

Tags: php, geojson

I obtained a very large geojson file covering (world-ski-mtn.geojson) all ski mountains of the world (310mb).  I do not want the world data and just want the France data.  How would I read this file and rewrite to file out with just France data in PHP?  The is "FR" mentioned in each record but how to read and filter.

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features":[
{"properties":{"activities":["nordic"],"generated":false,"id":"5d0baf79bc790209271afd09bbf3e21c923da6a2","location":{"iso3166_1Alpha2":"FR","iso3166_2":null,"localized":{"en":{"country":"France","region":null,"locality":null}}},"name":"Domaine Nordique de Pessade","runConvention":"europe","sources":[{"type":"openstreetmap","id":"relation/2754619"}],"status":"operating","type":"skiArea","websites":["http://www.tourisme-lescheires.com/les-activites-nordiques.html"],"statistics":{"runs":{"byActivity":{"nordic":{"byDifficulty":{"novice":{"count":3,"lengthInKm":2.158222657716816,"minElevation":1179.76293945312,"maxElevation":1241.02416992188,"combinedElevationChange":46.74377441407978},"easy":{"count":4,"lengthInKm":2.2528948156563886,"minElevation":1223.2634277343798,"maxElevation":1269.7160644531202,"combinedElevationChange":77.51440429685863},"other":{"count":7,"lengthInKm":8.737367497472203,"minElevation":1203.24682617188,"maxElevation":1446.0247802734398,"combinedElevationChange":366.62219238280954}}}},"minElevation":1179.76293945312,"maxElevation":1446.0247802734398},"lifts":{"byType":{}},"maxElevation":1446.0247802734398,"minElevation":1179.76293945312}},"type":"Feature","geometry":{"coordinates":[2.8720576963815803,45.62683955065789],"type":"Point"}}
,
{"properties":{"activities":["downhill","nordic"],"generated":false,"id":"f9a7b501ed966ed140fc2b5290e472c0a825d9be","location":{"iso3166_1Alpha2":"FR","iso3166_2":null,"localized":{"en":{"country":"France","region":null,"locality":null}}},"name":"Cauterets Pont d'Espagne","runConvention":"europe","sources":[{"type":"openstreetmap","id":"relation/2873910"}],"status":"operating","type":"skiArea","websites":[],"statistics":{"runs":{"byActivity":{"nordic":{"byDifficulty":{"novice":{"count":4,"lengthInKm":1.4561676423330407,"minElevation":1515.00061035156,"maxElevation":1544.46008300781,"combinedElevationChange":14.598876953139097},"easy":{"count":12,"lengthInKm":7.557498528921144,"minElevation":1531.1962890625,"maxElevation":1660.64587402344,"combinedElevationChange":236.31213378904022},"intermediate":{"count":1,"lengthInKm":1.7299713686348341,"minElevation":1645.50512695312,"maxElevation":1745.72180175781,"combinedElevationChange":96.50671386718955}}},"downhill":{"byDifficulty":{"intermediate":{"count":1,"lengthInKm":0.8539627981775926,"minElevation":1553.6240234374998,"maxElevation":1757.25048828125,"combinedElevationChange":203.62646484375023},"easy":{"count":1,"lengthInKm":1.6256735065210572,"minElevation":1515.00061035156,"maxElevation":1757.25048828125,"combinedElevationChange":241.24987792969},"novice":{"count":2,"lengthInKm":0.36506435611032134,"minElevation":1540.71752929688,"maxElevation":1571.4881591796902,"combinedElevationChange":52.396362304680224}}}},"minElevation":1515.00061035156,"maxElevation":1757.25048828125},"lifts":{"byType":{"gondola":{"count":1,"lengthInKm":0.4203286202552854,"minElevation":1480.41467285156,"maxElevation":1541.74780273438,"combinedElevationChange":55.87353515624977},"chair_lift":{"count":1,"lengthInKm":0.6211856955141307,"minElevation":1517.0473632812502,"maxElevation":1755.25048828125,"combinedElevationChange":238.20312499999977},"platter":{"count":2,"lengthInKm":0.3429539521126189,"minElevation":1541.71752929688,"maxElevation":1574.97583007812,"combinedElevationChange":54.88403320310999}},"minElevation":1480.41467285156,"maxElevation":1755.25048828125},"maxElevation":1755.25048828125,"minElevation":1515.00061035156}},"type":"Feature","geometry":{"coordinates":[-0.15893142323129938,42.84794797397566],"type":"Point"}}
]}
```

Comment: can you show me the complete geojson data

Answer (score 0):

For the specific geojson mentioned, my solution was as follows and I used ci4;

```
public function ski_index()
{      
    helper("filesystem");
     
    // Read the JSON file         
    $json = file_get_contents(WRITEPATH.'/ski/raw_data/ski_areas.geojson');

    // Decode the JSON file to an array
    $array_data = json_decode($json,true);
     
    // for the view
    $this->data['array_data'] = $array_data;       

    // $new_array will collected filtered ski resorts by country
    $new_array = array();
    
    $j=1;
    foreach ($array_data['features'] as $value){
        // if isset and filter by country
        if (isset($value['properties']['location']['iso3166_1Alpha2']) && $value['properties']['location']['iso3166_1Alpha2'] == 'FR'){
            array_push($new_array, $value);
            $j++; // show how many mountains
        }
    }
    
    // reconstruct by putting the array into FeatureCollection
    $reassemble_data = array ('type'=>'FeatureCollection', 'features'=>$new_array);
    
    // convert it back to json/geojson
    $this->data['new_array'] = json_encode($reassemble_data);     

    //write out to new file
    $file_content = $this->data['new_array'];
    if (!write_file(WRITEPATH."/ski/filtered_data/france_ski_resorts.geojson", $file_content)){
        echo "Error - cannot write to path";
    } else {
        echo "Success - written to file";
    }
    return view('/Admin/Ski/ski_index', $this->data );
}
```

Sure not the best code but the concept is there.